# Laravel passes a question mark in route()

Tags: php, laravel

My route function in Laravel adds a question mark (?), instead of a slash (/)

```
route('servers.index', 321); // http://domain/public_html/server?321
```

I want it to return http://domain.com/public_html/clientarea/server/321

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'clientarea'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index');

    Route::get('server/{id}', 'ServersController@index');
});

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('servers', 'ServersController');
```

Comment: Please show the relevant route from `routes.php`

Comment: Answer updates. Please notice i updated what i want in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into how the `route()` function is supposed to work. For example, you should name the route if you plan to reference it with `route()`. Once you have it named, you must make sure you're passing in the parameters correctly as Lukas said.

If Laravel can't find matching parameters defined for the route, it will default to making the paramaters a part of the query string. Since the route doesn't exist, it won't be able to find matching parameters to what you're passing in.

Take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 2):

The `route` function expects an array for parameters. You can either pass the values by name of the parameter or by order

```
route('servers.index', array(321));
```

or this (assuming the parameter is called `id`

```
route('servers.index', array('id' => 321));
```

Comment: That returns it as a get request
domain.com/server/?id=321

Comment: You don't even have a route named `servers.index`

Comment: My fault. I should have mentioned i have a resource for both users and servers.

Comment: I see.. That changes everything. Because the `index` action doesn't take any parameters. Are you looking for `show`?

Comment: Actually i made a parameter in index(). But i can also see i should use the show(). Thanks.

Comment: @andershagbard Please also be advised, in the routes file the route "server/{id}" has been defined, but is pointing at "ServersController@index", however it is not a named route. Meanwhile, "servers" points to the resource controller "ServersController" meaning "servers.index" will be set to the resource controller route, not the one as you maybe expect, in the "clientarea" route group.

Comment: @andershagbard John's right. I'd recommend you don't mix RESTful controllers/routes with "normal" ones. And you can't change the method signature if you use `Route::resource`

Comment: Correct John. I figured i could put my Resource routes at top of routes.php, and then override them as i please.
@Lukasgeiter This will do for development :)
Bot your answers helped to my solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from the laravel forums

```
$url = URL::route('welcome') . '#hash';
return Redirect::to($url); // domain.com/welcome#hash
```

http://laravel.io/forum/02-07-2014-how-to-append-hashtag-to-end-of-url-with-redirect